# I have tried many solutions but image is not showing when I run server. ;( on django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        **<img class="img-fluid" src="{{project.image}}">**
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>About the project:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
        <br>
        <h5>Technology used:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.technology_used }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

> I got this error:

```
[20/Feb/2021 21:49:31] "GET /project/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1427
Not Found: /project/static/img/1-webgrow.jpg
```

and the static folder is in project directory.

> This is the view function:

```
def details(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'project': project
    }
    return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to use .url in your code
It should be like this

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{project.image.url}}">
```

and also, the images of models are not stored in statics folder, their in media root